# Unable to share ufsd file system folder through nfs client

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

I have pen drive and mounted on ufsd(Universal file system ) file system in linux.I want to share that folder through nfs client.I have installed nfs server and put a entry in the /etc/exports file in server machine.I installed nfs client in client linux machine.From client machine i am not able to mount the folder.Could you tell me whether nfs server will support ufsd file system or not ?.

Command in client machine
mount -t nfs ip_address:/root/ufsd_pen_drive /root/data

Error is
         failed, reason given by server: Permission denied

But in the server side the log from /var/log/messages

```
         authenticated mount request from
```

Thanks

Comment: UFS does support exporting on NFS. Perhaps your firewall is blocking it. Turn it off and retry.

Comment: i am not using UFS.i am using Universal file system driver(UFSD).nfs mount is working for ext3 file system in the same machine.

Comment: Are you referring to http://www.paragon-software.com/technologies/ufsd/ ? If yes, then your best bet is to ask the vendor.